# Are there any drawing plugins for RoR or JQuery?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, canvas

I am writing a web based application using Ruby on Rails. In one of the forms the users would need to draw something with a mouse and label the object with some text. In short, I need a

1. Simple paint like application on which I can draw with a mouse.
2. Write simple text.
3. Store the painted diagram as a file for future editing.
4. Export the pained diagram as a gif/jpeg image.

An example can be found at http://charles-harvey.co.uk/examples/paint/. Here are my questions:

1. Are there any RoR plugins that allow me to add a paint like object to a form?
2. If not are there any JQuery plugins that have a simple paint like application that I can include in rails?
3. Any more pointers?

I can write a simple canvas application, but I am on a very tight deadline and prefer to use something that is already tested.

PS:  I found a link for such an application but forgot to bookmark it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm looking for something similar - came across this site today that looks useful:

http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Answer (score 3):

1. i dont know about plugins for painting. That question is better in Rails forums
2. http://caimansys.com/painter/ here you can download the sourcecode :)
3. i hope i can help u

Answer (score 0):

This blog had a good example using jquery:
http://motyar.blogspot.com/2010/01/draw-with-jquery.html